# Using Date Picker object on Xcode 10 to get time input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm very new to iOS development and mainly learn only through online tutorials as they're the easiest to follow but I could not find anything that helps my specific case of using Date Picker from the object library in Xcode 10 to get user input: time. I'm creating an app that requires the user to give arrival and departure time inputs and for the code to count the duration in hours and minutes from those inputs. Would be great if someone could show me how I go about this specifically from my code because I'm very new to coding and it's difficult for me to learn from thread discussions as I get confused on what goes where. Thanks!

I have only put the two Date picker objects from the library, set the mode to Time from the attribute interface and connected the two objects into the code with Outlet and Action each.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var atPickerOutlet: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func atPicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker)
    {

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var dtPickerOutlet: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func dtPicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker)
    {

    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: A date picker is not a UIPickerView so get rid of all the UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate cruft. Just configure the date picker in Time mode and set up a value changed action handler, as you seem to have done.

Comment: @matt He has another pickerView in the same view controller. He is using data source and delegate for that pickerView

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `IBAction` for these two date pickers. Create a new `IBAction` for the `calculate` button and find the difference between the two dates using [`timeIntervalSince(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779636-timeintervalsince)

```
@IBAction func calculateBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let interval = Int(dtPickerOutlet.date.timeIntervalSince(atPickerOutlet.date))
    let seconds = interval % 60
    let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
    let hours = (interval / 3600)
    print(String(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d",hours,minutes,seconds))
}
```

Comment: so from my code as of right now, i'd have to remove (disconnect?) ``` IBAction ``` from the two date pickers but leave their two Outlets as it is?

Comment: @IrfanHakim Yes